# Update a custom font file without publish an app update. Appcelerator

Tags: fonts, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I created an application with Appcelerator Alloy for iOS and Android. In my app I use a custom font created with icomoon, I have several categories and I assign each a symbol of the font. Now I can create new categories through a database and I would like to assign new symbols. I would like to add new symbols to the file font without having to publish an update of the application.

Is possible download through Internet the new font file and update this into the application in execution? Where could save the new file of the font?

Answer (score 0):

A really good question, [the filesystem docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Filesystem_Access_and_Storage) say that Resources (where the font files will reside) is read only on a real device, so I don't think that without some hackish solution you can update the font file easily.

Update from the comments: Expansion files ([android](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/14836#!overview), [iOS](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19069)) can be a solution.

Comment: Do you know if is posible host the font file on a ftp and use it remotely in the application?

Comment: No, I don't think that it is possibile, but maybe I found something useful, I remembered that it is possibile to download assets (eg, in games where they are really big), so looking around a bit I found [this module](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/14836#!overview) for android, iOS it seems that [it isn't still supported](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19069).

Answer (score 0):

On iOS you might be able to use:

https://github.com/dbankier/TiDynamicFont